# $cl(\mathbb{Q}\times \{1\})=\mathbb{R}\times \{1\}$

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove that in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ one have $cl(\mathbb{Q}\times \{1\})=\mathbb{R}\times \{1\}$?

Can I see this without using $cl(A\times B)=cl(A)\times cl(B)$ for product topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}\times \{1\}$. Then $y=1$ and $x \in cl( \mathbb Q).$ Hence $x= \lim r_n$ for some sequence $(r_n)$ with $r_n \in \mathbb Q$ for all $n$. It follows that

$$(r_n,1) \to (x,y).$$

Thus $(x,y) \in cl(\mathbb{Q}\times \{1\}).$

Comment: sorry what does "cl" represent? Closure?

Comment: @Adam: yes, closure.

Comment: Ok thankyou I'm new to topology.